# Was wondering when and why it produces empty strings

Tags: python, string

This is my piece of code and I am wondering why it produces an empty string

```
xs = "0123456789"

x = xs[4:-5:-1]

print(x)
```

Comment: Probably want to read through this: [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing).

Comment: Do you understand the extended slice syntax in general? What the `4`, `-5`, and `-1` mean individually?

Comment: A slice `[i:j:k]` means ["slice of s from i to j with step k"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations). For the slice `[4:-5]` in your case, however, there is no way to step through it with stepsize -1; you can only step from 4 to -5 forward. If you would use, e.g., `[4:-8]`, you can only step backward through it: `[4:-8:-1`] therefore does work, and produces `"43"`. You get an empty string in the first case, because you start at `[4]`, go back, and immediately hit a boundary: there are no (more) characters in that direction.

Comment: @chepner yes I understand 4 is the start of the slice and it includes it while -5 is the end of the slice and it starts from the right side starting with index -1. So if we were to slice it without the step of -1 we would get only 4. But I don't understand how the step makes it an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

A negative step doesn't simply reverse the result of a "positively stepped" slice. It affects the condition under which the slice is "terminated".

`xs[x:y:-1]` consists of `xs[k]` where `x >= k > y`. In this case, there is no `k` that satisfies `k > y`, because (after adjusting the negative index to its corresponding positive value) `x >= y` is false. As a result, no elements of the string are used to build the result.

---

`xs[x:-y] == xs[x:len(xs) - y]`, so

```
xs[4:-5:-1] == xs[4:len(xs) - 5:-1]
         == xs[4:10-5:-1]
         == xs[4:5:-1]
```

There is no `k` such that `4 >= k > 5`.

Comment: oh wow, never thought of a negative slice more than it moves it reversed by the number u put there. thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

According to python slicing syntax:

```
array[start:stop:step] # first element is start index, second is stop index and last is the step.
```

So, in your case, xs[4:-5:-1] starts with index 4, ends with index -5, and has a step of -1.

If you would have used xs[4::-1], the output would be '43210', but since -5 is not reachable with step of -1, you get an empty array.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by not reachable with a step of -1. Without the step, xs[4:-5] you get only '4' but when you apply the step it prints empty. I'm really confused on why

Comment: Because the step determines how the start and stop indices are used, not just the order in which elements from `xs[4:-5]` are presented.